# Upper radiator hose smoking

Tags: bmw, overheating, radiator

Steam coming out of the hose where upper radiator hose connects to the radiator. Hose itself has no damage just seems to steam from where it connects to the radiator. Car overheating

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Have you tried to tighten the radiator clamp?

Comment: Yes, I have. The tighter the clamp is, it just slows down the steam coming out from the hose connected to the radiator. Seems as if the radiator is clogged or something.

Answer (score 2):

Three possibilities come to my mind:

1. As noted in the first comment above, your hose clamp is failing or loose.  Check it.
2. The hose is damaged or leaking.  Replace it.
3. The radiator fitting is damaged or leaking.  This may require replacing the radiator.

Also, I'll add, based on later information that you posted.  Perhaps this is not the root problem.  If your radiator is clogged or the thermostat is failed and the pressure cap is malfunctioning, then perhaps this is the next weakest link.

Comment: Can't seem to find anything online that is similar to my case. Can I send you a video through email or something? I think it'd be much easier to explain through a video

Comment: This is the right answer.  You must confirm there is no leak in both the hose and connection point.  Steam is going to be from a very small crack.  Your bmw cannot operate with even a small leak in the system.   The plastic or hose may even appear to NOT be cracked on visual inspection.